# What's wrong in my converting .PDE to .JS?

Tags: processing, p5.js, converters

Hello coding community I need your help.
I took a sketch from openprocessing and I need to convert it into p5.js. The first script is the source code, then below will by my translation. I'm not sure about the syntax.

```
float x, y, x2, y2, rad, rad2, dist, dist2;
float deg, incr, yIn, rotateBy, ang;


void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(#02021A);
  incr = 1; // numVerts = 360/incr
  rad = -20;
  rad2 = -160;
  dist = 500;
  dist2 = 550;
}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(#02021A, 10);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(random(0, 255), 255, 255);
  
  rotateBy += .003;
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(rotateBy);
  deg = 0;
  while (deg <= 360) {
    deg += incr;
    ang = radians(deg);
    x = cos(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(y/100, yIn)));
    y = sin(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(x/80, yIn)));
    ellipse(x, y, 1.5, 1.5);
    x2 = sin(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    y2 = cos(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    ellipse(x2, y2, 1, 1);
  }
  yIn += .005;
  popMatrix();
}
```

This what I've done.
p5.js:

```
let x, y, x2, y2, rad, rad2, dist, dist2;
let deg, incr, yIn, rotateBy, ang;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background('#02021A');
  incr = 1; // numVerts = 360/incr
  rad = -20;
  rad2 = -160;
  dist = 500;
  dist2 = 550;
}

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill('#02021A');
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(random(0, 255), 255, 255);
  
  rotateBy += '.003';
  push();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(rotateBy);
  deg = 0;
  while (deg <= 360) {
    deg += incr;
    ang = radians(deg);
    x = cos(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(y/100, yIn)));
    y = sin(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(x/80, yIn)));
    ellipse(x, y, 1.5, 1.5);
    x2 = sin(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    y2 = cos(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    ellipse(x2, y2, 1, 1);
  }
  yIn += '.005';
  pop();
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Could you help me understand if the syntax is the same in these two languages.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Does it throw any errors? Does it return unexpected results? Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ah ok sorry. In my translation, when I run it in p5 editor I only see the background color of the canvas. When I run the script in processing app, I see the visualization.

Comment: Well, do you see any errors in the console? Have you tried debugging if your `draw` function is even called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but there are a couple of gotchas:

1. you declare variables at the top (e.g. `float x, y, x2, y2, rad, rad2, dist, dist2;`, etc.), however you don't initialize them with values. Because JavaScript is untyped (unlike Java), the interpreter can't guess what type you meant and the variables will be initialised to `undefined` (while in Java, because they're `float` type they'll default to `0`). Doing math operations on `undefined` results in `NaN` (not a number).
2. you're accidentally incrementing some values by strings instead of floats:  `rotateBy += '.003'; yIn += '.005';`
3. optional: `fill(#02021A, 10);` won't work in p5.js, however you can use fill(r,g,b,a) and pass your values in hex notation: `fill(0x02, 0x02, 0x1A, 10);`

This is your code with these two fixes applied:

```js
let x = 0, y = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, rad = 0, rad2 = 0, dist = 0, dist2 = 0;
let deg = 0, incr = 0, yIn = 0, rotateBy = 0, ang = 0;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background('#02021A');
  incr = 1; // numVerts = 360/incr
  rad = -20;
  rad2 = -160;
  dist = 500;
  dist2 = 550;
}

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(0x02, 0x02, 0x1A, 10);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(random(0, 255), 255, 255);
  rotateBy += 0.003;
  push();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(rotateBy);
  deg = 0;
  while (deg <= 360) {
    deg += incr;
    ang = radians(deg);
    x = cos(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(y/100, yIn)));
    y = sin(ang) * (rad + (dist * noise(x/80, yIn)));
    ellipse(x, y, 1.5, 1.5);
    x2 = sin(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    y2 = cos(ang) * (rad2 + (dist2 * noise(y2/20, yIn)));
    ellipse(x2, y2, 1, 1);
  }
  yIn += 0.005;
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

That looks pretty cool! Have fun !